# Maintenance Cleanup Task not working

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a cleanup task for cleaning out old backups. It hasn't been running. Well, it's been starting, but failing every time.

The log file says: "Executed as user: [omitted]. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved. Started: 3:00:00 AM Progress: 2015-02-19 03:00:04.67 Source: {1B09CDD3-A5E1-4C82-AEC6-4E36DD2BA8DC} Executing query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete End Progress DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). Started: 3:00:00 AM Finished: 3:00:05 AM Elapsed: 4.594 seconds. The package execution failed. The step failed."

When I look at the task, I notice a red x on it that says "No connection manager specified" or " There were errors during task validation." I can only assume this is the reason.

My other ones are fine.

Someone suggested this to me "Have you opened the DTSX package to see what is in there for a connection. It sounds like nothing is in there for whatever reason. "

To which, I answered "I don't know what that is. But, I did open the properties and Connection is blank. All the others say "Local Server Connection".

I wonder if I need to be on the server to make changes. I usually manage things from my own PC. In the past I thought I only had to go to the server to create new plans, not change existing ones. And I think this one was working fine until I changed the "Delete files older than" setting. "

I'd love some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it myself.  I am still not totally sure why this happened; maybe someone can shed some light on that.  But, I open up the step and the Connection part was blank.  I entered in all the credentials and changed the schedule to now to test and my files cleaned up.

Comment: This can happen if you are modifying your Maintenance Plans from different machines (different instances of SQL Server Management studio) - the connection files used in editing plan are stored on the computer that's running SSMS, not the actual database server